# Writing nested path parameters in FeathersJS

Tags: rest, feathersjs

How to generate multi level path parameters in feathers js like below :

`api.com/category/catergoryId/subCatergory/subCatergoryId`

Answer (score 9):

The following is taken from [this Feathers FAQ entry](https://docs.feathersjs.com/faq/readme.html#how-do-i-do-nested-or-custom-routes):

> Normally we find that they actually aren't needed and that it is much better to keep your routes as flat as possible. For example something like `users/:userId/posts` is - although nice to read for humans - actually not as easy to parse and process as the equivalent `/posts?userId=<userid>` that is already supported by Feathers out of the box. Additionaly, this will also work much better when using Feathers through websocket connections which do not have a concept of routes at all.
>
> However, nested routes for services can still be created by registering an existing service on the nested route and mapping the route parameter to a query parameter like this:

```
app.use('/posts', postService);
app.use('/users', userService);

// re-export the posts service on the /users/:userId/posts route
app.use('/users/:userId/posts', app.service('posts'));

// A hook that updates `data` with the route parameter
function mapUserIdToData(hook) {
  if(hook.data && hook.params.userId) {
    hook.data.userId = hook.params.userId;
  }
}

// For the new route, map the `:userId` route parameter to the query in a hook
app.service('users/:userId/posts').hooks({
  before: {
    find(hook) {
      hook.params.query.userId = hook.params.userId;
    },
    create: mapUserIdToData,
    update: mapUserIdToData,
    patch: mapUserIdToData
  }  
})
```

> Now going to `/users/123/posts` will call `postService.find({ query: { userId: 123 } })` and return all posts for that user.

Comment: Isn't `postService` equivalent to app.service('posts')? If yes, then why did you use `app.service('posts')` instead of `postService`?